# downloading XML in angular

Tags: angular, xml, download, angular15

I'm trying to make a method which download the return the API to XML file.

I did this method to make the request in the API:

```
public getXML(ano:any,mes:any,glosadas:any):Observable<Blob>{
const token = this.token.retornaToken();
const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization:`Bearer ${token}`});

return this.http.get(`API/xml?TpoRelatorio=1&NroGspContratado=&NroProtocolo=&NmeCliente=&SomenteGlosadas=${glosadas}&Ano=${ano}&Mes=${mes}&Page=1&Count=999999999`,{ headers, responseType:'blob' })}
```

I thought that was just needed to call `getXML()` in component.ts, but it didn't worked...

What should I do in component.ts?

Comment: Have you tried using the `download` attribute on a link? `<a href="API/xml?TpoRelatorio......" download="some-file.xml">`

Comment: you must call getXML().subscribe((xml)=>{})  I think you missed subscribe.

Comment: Yes,I missed it, but what I add inside the subscribe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was using the Blob object.

The method:

```
this.homeService
  .getXML(this.ano,this.mes,this.glosadas)
  .subscribe(data =>{
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  var blob = new Blob([data],{
    type:'text/xml'
  })
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  element.href = url;
  element.setAttribute('download','file.xml');
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
})
```